# How to convert [2,3,4] to [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2] to utilize tf.math.segment_sum?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Assume I have an array like [2,3,4], I am looking for a way in NumPy (or Tensorflow) to convert it to [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2] to apply tf.math.segment_sum() on a tensor that has a size of 2+3+4.

No elegant idea comes to my mind, only loops and list comprehension.

Comment: What you've shown can be done with the standard library. Can you explain further why it has to be done with numpy or tensorflow?

Comment: What's inelegant about loops and list comprehensions?

Comment: Numpy would be preferred for performance as this would be done on arrays that are very large. But would be happy to see how this can be done with standard library for the inspiration.

Comment: This would be a fun code golf!

Answer (score 8):

Would something like this work for you?

```
import numpy
arr = numpy.array([2, 3, 4])
numpy.repeat(numpy.arange(arr.size), arr)
# array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use numpy.  You can use nothing but list comprehensions:

```
>>> foo = [2,3,4]
>>> sum([[i]*foo[i] for i in range(len(foo))], [])
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

It works like this:

You can create expanded arrays by multiplying a simple one with a constant, so `[0] * 2` == `[0,0]`.  So for each index in the array, we expand with `[i]*foo[i]`.  In other words:

```
>>> [[i]*foo[i] for i in range(len(foo))]
[[0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2]]
```

Then we use `sum` to reduce the lists into a single list:

```
>>> sum([[i]*foo[i] for i in range(len(foo))], [])
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Because we are "summing" lists, not integers, we pass `[]` to `sum` to make an empty list the starting value of the sum.

(Note that this likely will be slower than numpy, though I have not personally compared it to something like @Patol75's answer.)

Comment: I did not know that you can pass `[]` to `sum()` to produce a list - I like it! :-)

Comment: I do wonder if it's too "clever", in which case you should use reduce directly: `reduce(lambda a,b:a+b, ([i]*foo[i] for i in range(len(foo))))`

Comment: Yours is considerably faster than mine; [`timeit.timeit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) with defaults gives yours 0.848s and mine 3.251s.

Comment: I believe that yours is also considerably faster than Patol75's answer, which [`timeit.timeit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) gives 2.579s.

Comment: For the given data, maybe.  I suspect theirs is faster if the array is very large.

Comment: @GorttheRobot The `reduce` function is no longer available in any version of Python that's not being sunset at the end of this year.

Comment: @mypetlion In Python 3, it's part of functools.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the answer from @Patol75 since it's neat. However, there is no pure tensorflow solution yet, so I provide one which maybe kinda complex. Just for reference and fun!

BTW, I didn't see `tf.repeat` this API in tf master. Please check this [PR](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/26517) which adds `tf.repeat` support equivalent to `numpy.repeat`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

repeats = tf.constant([2,3,4])
values = tf.range(tf.size(repeats))  # [0,1,2]

max_repeats = tf.reduce_max(repeats)  # max repeat is 4

tiled = tf.tile(tf.reshape(values, [-1,1]), [1,max_repeats])  # [[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2]]

mask = tf.sequence_mask(repeats, max_repeats)  # [[1,1,0,0],[1,1,1,0],[1,1,1,1]]

res = tf.boolean_mask(tiled, mask)  # [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Patol75's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58652349/6144626) uses Numpy but [Gort the Robot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58652438/6144626) is actually faster (on your example list at least).

I'll keep this answer up as another solution, but it's slower than both.

Given that `a = [2,3,4]` this could be done using a loop like so:

```py
b = []

for i in range(len(a)):
   for j in range(a[i]):
      b.append(range(len(a))[i])
```

Which, as a list comprehension one-liner, is this diabolical thing:

```py
b = [range(len(a))[i] for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(a[i])]
```

Both end up with `b = [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]`.